# SQL Variable, How to do it?

Tags: sql, oracle, variables

I have this SQL:

```
DROP TABLE MISSINGTABLE;

CREATE TABLE MISSINGTABLE (
  TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2 (70),
  DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2 (1000)
)

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MISSINGTABLES AS
  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO MISSINGTABLE
      ((((SELECT TABLE_NAME, 'Missing Table on PEKA_ERP_001' Description FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER = 'ASE_ERP_001')
      MINUS
      (SELECT TABLE_NAME, 'Missing Table on PEKA_ERP_001' Description FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER = 'PEKA_ERP_001'))
        UNION
      ((SELECT TABLE_NAME, 'Missing Table on ASE_ERP_001' Description FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER = 'PEKA_ERP_001')
      MINUS
      (SELECT TABLE_NAME, 'Missing Table on ASE_ERP_001' Description FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER = 'ASE_ERP_001'))));
  END;
```

So, how u can see, I'm creating a Table and then a Procedure, which fills the Table.
Now I want **2 Variables for these Arguments**: `'PEKA_ERP_001'` and `'ASE_ERP_001'` (so I don't always need to write it manually, because this values changes a lot)

I tried this (*included only the first part of above Statement*):

```
DECLARE
  S1 VARCHAR2(100) := 'ASE_ERP_001';
  S2 VARCHAR2(100) := 'PEKA_ERP_001';
  TableMissing VARCHAR(100) := 'Missing Table on ';
  Apostrophe VARCHAR(10) := '''';
  BEGIN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MISSINGTABLES AS BEGIN INSERT INTO MISSINGTABLE (SELECT TABLE_NAME, ' || Apostrophe || TableMissing || S2 || Apostrophe || ' Description FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE OWNER = ' || Apostrophe || S1 || Apostrophe || ')' || ' END;');
END;
```

It creates The Procedure, but the Procedure contains the "CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE" itself and its showing me an error... (I cannot execute the Procedure)

Can anyone help me? **How can I write the first SQL Statement at the Head which works, only with 2 Variables more**, `ASE_ERP_001` and `PEKA_ERP_001` ?

EDIT:

Statement:

```
 DECLARE
  S1 VARCHAR2(100) := 'ASE_ERP_001';
  S2 VARCHAR2(100) := 'PEKA_ERP_001';
  TabelleFehlt VARCHAR(100) := 'Diese Tabelle fehlt ';
  Hochkomma VARCHAR(10) := '''';
  BEGIN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MISSINGTABLES AS BEGIN INSERT INTO MISSINGTABLE (SELECT TABLE_NAME, ' || Hochkomma || TabelleFehlt || S2 || Hochkomma || ' Beschreibung FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE OWNER = ' || Hochkomma || S1 || Hochkomma || ') END;');
END;
```

The Statement Above Creates a Procedure. 
But it also shows me this:

```
    ORA-06512: in Row 7
    24344. 00000 -  "success with compilation error"
    *Cause:    A sql/plsql compilation error occurred.
    *Action:   Return OCI_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO along with the error code
```

And The PROCEDURE Itselfs Contains this:

```
    create or replace
PROCEDURE MISSINGTABLES AS BEGIN INSERT INTO MISSINGTABLE (SELECT TABLE_NAME, 'Diese Tabelle fehlt PEKA_ERP_001' Beschreibung FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE OWNER = 'ASE_ERP_001') END;
```

But it should not Contain "Create or Replace Procedure MISSINGTABLES" etc. only the INSERT STatement, I cannot execute the Procedure anyway..

even better would be to use the script from bpgergo, if it would go.

Comment: What is your business logic here?  Why are you dynamically creating a procedure.  Why not create a static proceudre and just tweaking the values of the variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope I did not mix the arguments up, you should check them again

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MISSINGTABLES (p_1 in varchar2, p_2 in varchar2)
AS
  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO MISSINGTABLE
      ((((SELECT TABLE_NAME, 'Missing Table on '||p_1 Description FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER = p_2)
      MINUS
      (SELECT TABLE_NAME, 'Missing Table on '||p_1 Description FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER = p_1))
        UNION
      ((SELECT TABLE_NAME, 'Missing Table on '||p_2 Description FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER = p_1)
      MINUS
      (SELECT TABLE_NAME, 'Missing Table on '||p_2 Description FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER = p_2))));
END;
```

**EDIT**

you would call this like:

```
begin
    MISSINGTABLES ('PEKA_ERP_001', 'ASE_ERP_001');
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just tried it, but I got this ErrorMessage: ´PLS-00201: 'MISSINGTABLES' must be declared
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:´

Comment: eMi, you have to define your procedure before you'd call it. had you successfully run `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MISSINGTABLES` before you called it?

Comment: Now I got this ErrorMessage: `ORA-06550: ROW 4, COLUMN 1:
PLS-00103: Found Symbol "CREATE" 
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:`

Comment: @eMI - that error indicates that you have a CREATE stateemnt int your procedure: we cannot execute DDL in PL/SQL (except through dynamic sql).  bpgergo's solution is indeed the correct one.  If it doesn't work for you it is because you have mistransacribed it.  If you want us to spot the bug you have to poste *the exact code* you are running.

Comment: Teamviewer? I tried bpgergos Code, it wont work.. In my opinion it also should work -_-

Comment: @eMI "it won't work" is insufficient information.  Give us details.  *how* doesn't it work? Help us to help you.  Or don't, the choice is yours.

Comment: I solved the problem! In the first Line of this SQL Statement (from bpgergo) a comma is missing.. Now It works fine :D Thx for Help guys

Answer (score 1):

The SQL that you are trying to execute immediate will be evaluated as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MISSINGTABLES AS 
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO MISSINGTABLE 
(SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, 'Missing Table on PEKA_ERP_001' Beschreibung 
 FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE OWNER = 'ASE_ERP_001')
END;
```

This probably isn't the logic that you actually want, but the immediate problem is that you are trying to populate a non-existant third column called Beschreibung instead of populating the second column, `DESCRIPTION` .

Comment: thats not the problem, I just changed the language of the script, cause there was everything on German. In my Workspace everything is correctly, I just changed it now to Description

Comment: @eMi: You have misunderstood the nature of the problem - your code has **three** columns, but MISSINGTABLE has **two** columns. It is the extraneous extra column (called `COLUMN_NAME` in your code) that is causing the error.

Comment: Oh yes, well watched! I removed it, but its still not working :( It creates the Procedure, but IN the procedure I have again the whole Code ("create or replace
PROCEDURE MISSINGTABLES AS BEGIN INSERT INTO MISSINGTABLE (SELECT TABLE_NAME...")

Comment: @eMi: Can you update the question with the whole comand you have issued, what it generates when run and why this is not what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest an improvement to your SELECT?

Here's a possible alternative:

```
SELECT
  TABLE_NAME,
  'Missing Table on'
  || CASE MAX(OWNER) WHEN 'PEKA_ERP_001' THEN 'ASE_ERP_001' ELSE 'PEKA_ERP_001' END
  AS Description
FROM ALL_TABLES
WHERE OWNER IN ('PEKA_ERP_001', 'ASE_ERP_001')
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

This query returns only rows where a `TABLE_NAME` has just one `OWNER`. The owner that is missing the table is then shown to be as the other one of the two being tested.

Using parameters, the entire `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement might look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MISSINGTABLES
(
  owner1 IN varchar2,
  owner2 IN varchar2
)
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO MISSINGTABLE
  (
  SELECT
    TABLE_NAME,
    'Missing Table on'
    || CASE MAX(OWNER) WHEN owner1 THEN owner2 ELSE owner1 END
    AS Description
  FROM ALL_TABLES
  WHERE OWNER IN (owner1, owner2)
  GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
  );
END;
```